# How to add computed columns in a multi-level column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-level

I have a multi-level column dataframe on the lines of one below:
[image]
How can I add columns 'Sales' = 'Qty' * 'Price' one each for each 'Year'?

The input dataframe in dictionary format:

```
{('Qty', 2001): [50, 50], ('Qty', 2002): [100, 10], ('Qty', 2003): [200, 20], ('Qty', 2004): [300, 30], ('Qty', 2005): [400, 40], ('Price', 2001): [20, 11], ('Price', 2002): [21, 12], ('Price', 2003): [22, 13], ('Price', 2004): [23, 14], ('Price', 2005): [24, 15]}
```

Currently, I am splitting the dataframe for each year separately and adding a computed column. If there is an easier method that would be great.

Here is the expected output
[image]

Comment: {('Qty', 2001): [50, 50], ('Qty', 2002): [100, 10], ('Qty', 2003): [200, 20], ('Qty', 2004): [300, 30], ('Qty', 2005): [400, 40], ('Price', 2001): [20, 11], ('Price', 2002): [21, 12], ('Price', 2003): [22, 13], ('Price', 2004): [23, 14], ('Price', 2005): [24, 15]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the required column names with a list comprehension, and then simply assign the multiplication ([`df.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html)).

```
new_cols = [('Sales', col) for col in df['Qty'].columns]
# [('Sales', 2001), ('Sales', 2002), ('Sales', 2003), ('Sales', 2004), ('Sales', 2005)]

df[new_cols] = df['Qty'].mul(df['Price'])

df

   Qty                     Price                     Sales                    \
  2001 2002 2003 2004 2005  2001 2002 2003 2004 2005  2001  2002  2003  2004   
0   50  100  200  300  400    20   21   22   23   24  1000  2100  4400  6900   
1   50   10   20   30   40    11   12   13   14   15   550   120   260   420   

         
   2005  
0  9600  
1   600
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us `stack` to flatten multiindex columns then multiply and reshape back using unstack

```
df.stack().eval('Sales = Price * Qty').unstack()
```

---

```
   Price                    Qty                       Sales                        
   2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005  2001  2002  2003  2004  2005
0    20   21   22   23   24   50  100  200  300  400  1000  2100  4400  6900  9600
1    11   12   13   14   15   50   10   20   30   40   550   120   260   420   600
```

Comment: Depending on your needs, you want to be a bit careful with this method, since `df.stack` sorts the values both for the columns (i.e. `Price, Qty` instead of `Qty, Price`) and the index (`2001, 2002` etc.). Of course, the years happen to be in order, so you don't see any change there, but that need not be the case. E.g., try `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Qty','Price'], [*'ZYXWV']])` before applying this method, and you'll see that all columns are moved around. First column becoming `('Price', 'V')` rather than `('Qty', 'Z')` etc.

Comment: Thanks  for bringing out another possibility! And thanks @ouroboros1 for pointing out what to watch out for when we use this